# Raphel - illustrator to SVG

Tags: raphael

Hi I am trying to find a good way to export illustrator svg objects to work with the Raphael javascript framework and still have full control over each of the elements.

lets say I have drawn a frog in illustrator...

http://jsfiddle.net/PqvqD/

nothing taxing there just a few circles and stuffs!

Looking down the the code line by line I can then add bits together

from

```
<ellipse style="fill:#528121;stroke:#52394A;stroke-width:4;stroke-miterlimit:10;" cx="202.5" cy="477" rx="17" ry="3.5"/>
```

I can do this

```
self.elements['frog'] = stage.context.set();
self.elements['frog'].push( stage.context.circle( 202.5, 477, 17, 3.5 ).attr({ fill: '#528121', stroke : '#52394A', 'stroke-width' : 4 }) );
stage.context.setFinish();
```

but when I get to the next line im stumpt because of the transform matrix, which I dont understand... I have tried

```
<ellipse transform="matrix(0.9915 0.1301 -0.1301 0.9915 63.9829 -8.3579)" style="fill:#528121;stroke:#52394A;stroke-width:4;stroke-miterlimit:10;" cx="95.969" cy="485.597" rx="21.833" ry="8.588"/>

self.elements['frog'] = stage.context.set();
self.elements['frog'].push( stage.context.circle( 202.5, 477, 17, 3.5 ).attr({ fill: '#528121', stroke : '#52394A', 'stroke-width' : 4 }) );
self.elements['frog'].push( stage.context.circle( 95.969, 485.597, 21.833, 8.588 ).matrix( 0.9915, 0.1301, -0.1301, 0.9915, 63.9829 -8.3579 ).attr({ fill: '#528121', stroke : '#52394A', 'stroke-width' : 4 }) );
stage.context.setFinish();
```

but I get an error

> Property 'matrix' of object [object Object] is not a function

any idea where im going wrong?

regards

Answer (score 1):

Do you know (and did you try) this one ? 
http://readysetraphael.com/

Comment: This looks very good! I will give it a whirl, looks a much simpler process than the one above.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to my question but thought id add some findings...
found this little tool: http://irunmywebsite.com/raphael/SVGTOHTML_LIVE90.php

basically I saved my layers out in illustrator (objects such as the frog) and saved them as SVG's. Whipped them into this site and then clicked "collect Raphael". this tool seems to remove all the transform and circles and rectangles and constructs all the elements using path... very good!

```
self.elements['frog'] = stage.context.set();
self.elements['frog'].push( stage.context.path( 'M 219.5 477 C 219.5 479.7 205.3 481.4 194 480 C 182.7 478.7 182.7 475.3 194 474 C 205.2 472.6 219.3 474.3 219.5 476.9' ).attr({ fill: '#528121', stroke : '#52394A', 'stroke-width' : 4 }) );
self.elements['frog'].push( stage.context.path( 'M 117.6 488.4 C 116.7 495 98.2 496.7 84.2 491.6 C 70.2 486.4 71.2 478.2 86.1 476.8 C 100.8 475.4 118.2 481.8 117.6 488.3' ).attr({ fill: '#528121', stroke : '#52394A', 'stroke-width' : 4 }) );
self.elements['frog'].push( stage.context.path( 'M 145.3 471.7 C 148.7 478.2 134.5 490.6 119.9 493.8 C 105.2 497.1 101.1 488.9 112.4 479.1 C 123.6 469.3 141.7 465.2 145.3 471.5' ).attr({'fill':'#528121','stroke':'#52394a','stroke-width':'4','stroke-miterlimit':'10','fill-opacity':'1','stroke-opacity':'1'}) );
self.elements['frog'].push( stage.context.path( 'M 206 479.1 C 206 502.2 170.6 516.6 142.3 505.1 C 113.9 493.6 113.9 464.7 142.3 453.1 C 170.3 441.7 205.4 455.7 206 478.6' ).attr({'fill':'#528121','stroke':'#52394a','stroke-width':'4','stroke-miterlimit':'10','fill-opacity':'1','stroke-opacity':'1'}) );
self.elements['frog'].push( stage.context.path( 'M 165.3 491.7 C 168.7 498.2 154.5 510.6 139.9 513.8 C 125.2 517.1 121.1 508.9 132.4 499.1 C 143.6 489.3 161.7 485.2 165.3 491.5' ).attr({'fill':'#528121','stroke':'#52394a','stroke-width':'4','stroke-miterlimit':'10','fill-opacity':'1','stroke-opacity':'1'}) );
self.elements['frog'].push( stage.context.path( 'M 135.7 509.7 C 135.7 517 117.4 521.5 102.9 517.8 C 88.4 514 88.4 504.8 103 501.2 C 117.4 497.7 135.4 502.2 135.7 509.5' ).attr({'fill':'#528121','stroke':'#52394a','stroke-width':'4','stroke-miterlimit':'10','fill-opacity':'1','stroke-opacity':'1'}) );
self.elements['frog'].push( stage.context.path( 'M 197.8 458.3 C 197.8 469.9 185.3 477.1 175.3 471.3 C 165.3 465.5 165.3 451.1 175.3 445.3 C 185.2 439.6 197.6 446.6 197.8 458.1' ).attr({'fill':'#ffffff','stroke':'#52394a','stroke-width':'5','stroke-miterlimit':'10','fill-opacity':'1','stroke-opacity':'1'}) );
self.elements['frog'].push( stage.context.path( 'M 194.7 460 C 194.7 465.9 188.3 469.6 183.2 466.6 C 178.1 463.7 178.1 456.3 183.2 453.4 C 188.2 450.4 194.6 454 194.7 459.9' ).attr({'fill':'#000000','stroke':'none','stroke-width':'0','fill-opacity':'1','stroke-opacity':'0'}) );
self.elements['frog'].push( stage.context.path( 'M 191 461.8 C 191 464 188.6 465.4 186.8 464.3 C 184.9 463.2 184.9 460.5 186.8 459.4 C 188.6 458.3 191 459.6 191 461.8' ).attr({'fill':'#ffffff','stroke':'none','stroke-width':'0','fill-opacity':'1','stroke-opacity':'0'}) );
self.elements['frog'].push( stage.context.path( 'M 185.8 458.4 C 185.8 459.4 184.8 460 184 459.5 C 183.1 459 183.1 457.8 184 457.3 C 184.8 456.9 185.8 457.4 185.8 458.4' ).attr({'fill':'#ffffff','stroke':'none','stroke-width':'0','fill-opacity':'1','stroke-opacity':'0'}) );
self.elements['frog'].push( stage.context.path( 'M 211.5 492 C 211.5 494.7 197.3 496.4 186 495 C 174.7 493.7 174.7 490.3 186 489 C 197.2 487.6 211.3 489.3 211.5 491.9' ).attr({'fill':'#528121','stroke':'#52394a','stroke-width':'4','stroke-miterlimit':'10','fill-opacity':'1','stroke-opacity':'1'}) );
stage.context.setFinish();
```

you can then move the frog:

```
self.elements['frog'].transform( 't' + x + ',' + y );
```

not the answer I was looking for but a solid alternative for the result I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, as the error says, matrix is not a function. It is actually a store of the matrix, and not manipulated via a function 'matrix', but by 'transform' you used later.

If you want to use a matrix, the transform string you will pass, will normally start with an m for matrix (as opposed to t translate, s scale, r rotate), and then the 6 transform elements as a string (or could all be as an array).

So using a similar example, you would do something like...

```
var paper = Raphael("container",400,400);

paper.setStart();

paper.circle( 20.5, 77, 17, 3.5 ).attr({ fill: '#528121', stroke : '#52394A', 'stroke-width' : 4 }) ;

paper.circle( 9.969, 48.597, 21.833, 8.588 ).transform( 'm0.9915, 0.1301, -0.1301, 0.9915, 63.9829 -8.3579' ).attr({ fill: '#528121', stroke : 'red', 'stroke-width' : 4 });

var frogSet = paper.setFinish();


frogSet.forEach( function( el ) { 
    el.transform('t150,50'); //do what you want, transform, maybe animate etc
} );
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/KFpNd/1/)

Comment: From reading, isn't the matrix used to control the bounding box of an element? Also can I ask why your example doesn't match the actual result?

Comment: Example was just easier for me to distinguish at the time, you can put your normal matrix and attributes in there. Was there somewhere in particular that made you think about the matrix controlling the bounding box ? I'm just not sure if its helpful or not to think of it like that.